# paypal sequence django python need explanation - process execute

Tags: python, django, rest, paypal

I am trying to refer to paypalrestsdk on my django app but not sure the sequence between authorize and execute
https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Python-SDK

I have created the payment and after that I redirect to the payment link using Authorize Payment. This will bring to paypal page.

Authorize Payment:

```
for link in payment.links:
    if link.rel == "approval_url":
        # Convert to str to avoid Google App Engine Unicode issue
        # https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-python/pull/58
        approval_url = str(link.href)
        print("Redirect for approval: %s" % (approval_url))
```

UPDATE (i will use this link to redirect to the approval_url):

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(approval_url)
```

Execute Payment

```
payment = paypalrestsdk.Payment.find("PAY-57363176S1057143SKE2HO3A")

if payment.execute({"payer_id": "DUFRQ8GWYMJXC"}):
  print("Payment execute successfully")
else:
  print(payment.error) # Error Hash
```

Do we still need to execute payment after authorize payment ? the payment made in authorize should execute already (ok i guess so since return_url seems to go to execute) then how should i process the return_url to obtain (payment id and payer_id)?

From here:
https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Python-SDK/blob/b376dc78579819cd9566aae2c3a8de9c9026cbfb/paypalrestsdk/api.py
It seems to return in this format

```
        >>> api.post("v1/payments/payment/PAY-1234/execute", { 'payer_id': '1234' })
```

what should be views.py and urls.py to process this format also ?

Comment: Yes, authorization is the action of the user to allow the payment. Execute will actually do the authorized payment.

Comment: i update a bit , i use return HttpResponseRedirect(approval_url), this will direct to payment page in paypal.com. Im not clear, when do i do execute ? here it seems to use just for verify but not execute https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Python-SDK/blob/eed15dd7f03cbf091014c1a4c3aff76f4ef554ec/samples/mobile_backend/paypal_client.py